# Can I add my existing html homepage google analytics code into new wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-ads-api

We are having a html website whose homepage and other few pages has google analytics code and keywords. Now we have created a new homepage on wordpress which will be our future homepage. So my question is can I use my existing homepage GA code into my new wordpress homepage? If yes then how? We don't want to lose our previous tracking data at any cost. 
How can use it? Please Help. 
TIA.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled "WordPress Google Analytics"? (This site is for programming related questions, and this is not a programming question - or at least it _shouldn't_ be).

Comment: Maybe this question would be better placed at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ Not sure how to 'vote' to get a question migrated over to the relevant Forum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your existing google analytics code by using WordPress plugins.
There are many plugins in WordPress which provides ability to integrate your google analytics code to your site and all pages dynamically and also display you a complete tracking reports as well.

here is one plugin link for your reference please check it.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/googleanalytics/

There are lot's of other plugins as well you can simply check out in WordPress plugins repository.

=> Also you can add your google analytics code programmatic as well.
Please copy below code and paste it into your activated themes functions.php file at the end of the file.

```
function add_google_analytics_code_to_pages(){
?>
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-ADD YOU GOOGLE ANALYTICS ID HERE', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
    <?php
}   
add_action("wp_head","add_google_analytics_code_to_pages");
```

Just add your google analytics tracking id into about script.
Replace your tracking id instead of this code.
'UA-ADD YOU GOOGLE ANALYTICS ID HERE'

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something here, sure!

All you have to do is enter your Google Tracking code inside the `<head>` tags, within the `header.php` template file.  Ideally, just before the closing `</head>` tag.

By inserting your Google Tracking code, within the `header.php` template file, every WordPress page will be tracked.

Your `header.php` template file will typically be found within the following directory path:

```
wp-content > themes > theme-name
```

If you are not the theme author, don't forget to create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  You will then need to insert the appropriate `header.php` template file within said Child Theme.

**Google Tag Assistance:**

For the most part, the above should resolve your problem.  You can check whether the Tracking code has been correctly installed by:

1. Reviewing the code within the Source Code
2. Installing [Google Tag Assistance](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) within Chrome

**Exception:**

Again, the above should be enough to resolve your issue.  Some themes however, do create different headers, for different pages of the site.  For example:  An eCommerce site may want a different header on their shop pages to their Blog Pages.  To achieve this, header template files, such as below would be created:

- `header-shop.php`
- `header-blog.php`
- `header-ppc.php`

To then 'call' each header, the following example PHP entry would be placed within the relevant template file(s):

```
<?php get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
```

'shop' being whatever word appends the `header-` file name.  In this case, 'shop', 'blog' and 'ppc'.

You do not need to worry much about this.  All you need to do, is head into the root of your theme as follows:

```
wp-content > themes > theme-name
```

Look for any files with begin with `header-` and ensure they contain the Google Tracking code.

In the event you are using a Child Theme, simply copy the `header-` files over to the root of your Child Theme *first* and then modify accordingly.

Hope this helps.